# Using move_alloc in a derived type

Tags: fortran, alloc, derived-types

I have written a derived type that stores a multidimensional array. The array will be read from a file to an array `b`. I then want to transfer `b` to the derived type `Space` using member `a`. The advantage for mvalloc is not having to allocate two large arrays which might create memory problems.

When I compile the code I am getting the error

```
Call Move_Alloc (b, t% a)
               1
Error: 'from' argument of 'move_alloc' intrinsic 
at (1) must be ALLOCATABLE
```

The type definition and relevant subroutine follows

```
Type, Public :: Space

  Character (Len=65) :: nm
  Real, Allocatable :: a(:,:,:) 

  Contains
    Procedure :: mvalloc => space_mvalloc

End Type Space


Subroutine space_mvalloc (t, b)

  Class (Space), Intent (InOut) :: t
  Real, Intent (InOut) :: b(:,:,:)

  Call Move_Alloc (b, t% a)

End Subroutine space_mvalloc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, the arguments to `move_alloc` must be allocatable. That's both of them.  `from` is the first, and this must be allocatable for the allocation to move from it.

You have

```
Subroutine space_mvalloc (t, b)

  Class (SField), Intent (InOut) :: t
  Real, Intent (InOut) :: b(:,:,:)

  Call Move_Alloc (b, t% a)
End Subroutine space_mvalloc
```

`b` here is not allocatable.  You should add that attribute, and ensure that the actual argument passed in is allocatable.

After the call to `move_alloc` `b`, and the corresponding actual argument, will be unallocated.

Comment: I understand. What are the implications when one declares an argument inside a subroutine as allocatable. And what might be the difference when I do not use the allocatable attribute?

Comment: There's a bit too much in that to address in a comment, but three quick points: an explicit interface will be required for the caller (which would be needed here anyway with the assumed-shape dummy); actual/effective argument must be allocatable; bounds of the array are passed.  [Other things also apply.]  "If you don't" has an easy answer: you can't use `move_alloc`.

Comment: Is that because I am going to do something related to its allocation status - reallocate it, deallocate?

Comment: Yes, you are "moving" the allocation.  The effect of that is that the second argument is (deallocated first if needed) allocated as the first and takes the values of the first.  The first then becomes unallocated.